# In Svelte, is there a way to undo invalid user input, without changing the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, svelte

In Svelte, is there a way to undo invalid user input, without triggering a momentarily fake property change for state?

For example ([try it online](https://svelte.dev/repl/a5bc00c245964b27bc750c1e8fba5bae?version=3.44.1)), when user types in `123a` in the `input` box, I want to covert it to a number and assign it `counter`.

For that, I have to introduce a temporary and redundant change to `counter` (using `Number.NaN` below). Otherwise, `counter` won't change, and `123a` will remain inside the `input` box, while I want to revert it back to `123`:

```html
<script>
    let count = 0;
    const handleClick = () => count++;
    const handleChange = async e => {
        const userValue = e.target.value;
        let newValue = userValue? parseInt(userValue): 0;
        if (isNaN(newValue)) newValue = count;
        count = Number.NaN;
        await Promise.resolve();
        count = newValue;           
    };  
</script>

Count: <button on:click={handleClick}>{count}</button>
<br />
A: <input value={count} on:input={handleChange} />
<br />
```

Is there a better way of doing it? Essentially, I want trigger a manual re-render for a part of my Svetle component, without changing the state.

Of course, in the event handler I could undo the change just by modifying `e.target.value` directly:

```javascript
const handleChange = async e => {
    const userValue = e.target.value;
    let newValue = userValue? parseInt(userValue): 0;
    if (isNaN(newValue)) newValue = count;
    if (newValue == count)
        e.target.value = count;
    else
        count = newValue;
};
```

But I wonder if there's a way to tell Svelte to re-render the whole `<input>`?

To compare, here's how I could do it in React ([try it online](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-js-hdhv9q?file=index.js)):

```jsx
function App() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const handleClick = () => setCount((count) => count + 1);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const userValue = e.target.value;
    let newValue = userValue ? parseInt(userValue) : 0;
    if (isNaN(newValue)) newValue = count;
    setCount(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <>
      Count: <button onClick={handleClick}>{count}</button>
      <br />
      A: <input value={count} onInput={handleChange} />
      <br />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to [`bind`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/text-inputs) count to the value of the input. [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/756a3db3848b4aa1ba206fc0f6f45e85?version=3.44.1)

```
<script>
  let count = 0;
  
  const handleClick = () => count++;
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const userValue = e.target.value;
    const newValue = userValue ? parseInt(userValue, 10) : 0;
  
    count = isNaN(newValue) ? count : newValue;
  };    
</script>

Count: <button on:click={handleClick}>{count}</button>
<br />
A: <input bind:value={count} on:input={handleChange} />
<br />
```

*Note: Remember to [always pass a radix to `parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters), it does not default to 10.*

Comment: Thanks! As a learning excersice, is there a way to force an update without `bind:value`? Or at least, plug in a callback into the binding pipeline?

Comment: bind is the most svelte, and the closest to the react useState example you've given, but alternatives are available if awkward. For example you could wrap the input element in a conditional that watches a value `{#if somecondition}<input>{:if}`...